# Check if user collected any points from my quiz

Tags: python

I have a quiz which adds points each time they answer right answer (well.. it does so properly) and I want to check if user has collected more than 0 points at the end.

Here's code I have to check if user has more than zero points (it doesn't work and its only a piece of whole code):

```
def end_of_quiz():
    global score
    if  score > "0" :
        print("Well Done, Your score is:")
        print(score)
    else:
        print("Sorry, you didn't get any points, you shall try again!")
```

How shall I change it to make it work

Comment: Should it be `score > "0"` or `score > 0`? `"0" ` is a string literal, `0` is the numerical zero...

Comment: is there a difference? i think it should be`score > "0"`

Comment: The code snippet you posted has at least three different problems. But more importantly, what do you actually want it to do if the user has more points than 0?

Comment: adding to mu, you'd want to leave out the quotes - the number of points is a number, not a string

Comment: oh and when i call that function it says 0

Comment: when i passed thew quiz with max points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [string literal for zero, `"0"`](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), instead of the numerical zero (`0`) for comparison.

This will evaluate to `False` for all numbers:

```
>>> -1 > "0"
False
>>> -10**10 > "0"
False
>>> 10**10 > "0"
False
>>> 1 > "0"
False
>>> 1 > 0
True
```

So instead, alter your method to compare with the numerical zero

```
def end_of_quiz():
    global score
    if  score > 0:
        print("Well Done, Your score is:")
        print(score)
    else:
        print("Sorry, you didn't get any points, you shall try again!")
```